# I can't restart apache

Tags: apache2

After a system release update, I cant restart my apache server!

```
 $ sudo service apache2 restart    

Job for apache2.service failed because the control process exited with error code. See "systemctl status apache2.service" and "journalctl -xe" for details.

 $ systemctl status apache2.service

● apache2.service - LSB: Apache2 web server
   Loaded: loaded (/etc/init.d/apache2; bad; vendor preset: enabled)
  Drop-In: /lib/systemd/system/apache2.service.d
           └─apache2-systemd.conf
   Active: failed (Result: exit-code) since Fr 2016-08-05 14:32:36 EDT; 1s ago
     Docs: man:systemd-sysv-generator(8)
  Process: 1654 ExecStop=/etc/init.d/apache2 stop (code=exited, status=0/SUCCESS)
  Process: 1800 ExecStart=/etc/init.d/apache2 start (code=exited, status=1/FAILURE)

Aug 05 14:32:36 enriquemorenotent apache2[1800]:  *
Aug 05 14:32:36 enriquemorenotent apache2[1800]:  * The apache2 configtest failed.
Aug 05 14:32:36 enriquemorenotent apache2[1800]: Output of config test was:
Aug 05 14:32:36 enriquemorenotent apache2[1800]: apache2: Syntax error on line 140 of /etc/apache2/apache2.conf: Syntax error on line 1 of /etc/apache2/mods-enabled/php5.load: Cannot load /usr/lib/apache2/modules/libphp5.so into server: /u
Aug 05 14:32:36 enriquemorenotent apache2[1800]: Action 'configtest' failed.
Aug 05 14:32:36 enriquemorenotent apache2[1800]: The Apache error log may have more information.
Aug 05 14:32:36 enriquemorenotent systemd[1]: apache2.service: Control process exited, code=exited status=1
Aug 05 14:32:36 enriquemorenotent systemd[1]: Failed to start LSB: Apache2 web server.
Aug 05 14:32:36 enriquemorenotent systemd[1]: apache2.service: Unit entered failed state.
Aug 05 14:32:36 enriquemorenotent systemd[1]: apache2.service: Failed with result 'exit-code'.
```

Line 140 for apache2.conf is this:

```
# It is also possible to configure the log level for particular modules, e.g.
# "LogLevel info ssl:warn"
#
LogLevel warn

# Include module configuration:
IncludeOptional mods-enabled/*.load    # <--- Line 140!
IncludeOptional mods-enabled/*.conf

# Include list of ports to listen on
Include ports.conf
```

## Update

I tried doing this:

```
$ sudo apt-get install libapache2-mod-php7

Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
E: Unable to locate package libapache2-mod-php7
```

or this:

```
$ sudo apt-get install libapache2-mod-php5

Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
Package libapache2-mod-php5 is not available, but is referred to by another package.
This may mean that the package is missing, has been obsoleted, or
is only available from another source

E: Package 'libapache2-mod-php5' has no installation candidate
```

nothing worked

Comment: EXACT the same problem: http://askubuntu.com/questions/536128/apache2-start-error-when-using-php5-module-ubuntu-server