# How to resolve "The apache2 configtest failed"?

Tags: 14.04, apache2

I get this error when I start apache2 service:

```
 * The apache2 configtest failed.
 Output of config test was:
 apache2: Syntax error on line 140 of /etc/apache2/apache2.conf:Syntax   error on line 1 of /etc/apache2/mods-enabled/php5.load: Cannot load /usr/lib   /apache2/modules/libphp5.so into server: /usr/lib/apache2/modules/libphp5.so: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory
 Action 'configtest' failed.
 The Apache error log may have more information.
```

I run it on ubuntu 14.04 64bit. How can I resolve it?

Comment: "Syntax error on line 140 of /etc/apache2/apache2.conf" Have a guess on what to do next ...

Comment: this is the syntax line 140 ---
IncludeOptional mods-enabled/*.load

Comment: @techraf no cheating :+) Here is the answer to the problem: http://askubuntu.com/a/536141/15811

Comment: i have install apt install libapache2-mod-php, but still get the same error

Comment: * Restarting web server apache2                                         [fail] 
 * The apache2 configtest failed.
Output of config test was:
apache2: Syntax error on line 141 of /etc/apache2/apache2.conf: Syntax error on line 3 of /etc/apache2/mods-enabled/dir.conf: </IfModule> without matching <IfModule> section
Action 'configtest' failed

Answer (score 0):

Check that `/usr/lib/apache2/modules/libphp5.so` exists and has the permissions of 644 (`sudo chmod 644 /usr/lib/apache2/modules/libphp5.so`) and is owned by root:root (`sudo chown root:root /usr/lib/apache2/modules/libphp5.so`).