# php5.load: Cannot load libphp5.so undefined symbol: unixd_config apache service not start

Tags: server, apache2, php

When I trying to restart apache service getting below error:

```
root@localhost:/# /etc/init.d/apache2 restart
[FAIL] Restarting web server: apache2 failed!
[warn] The apache2 configtest failed. ... (warning).
Output of config test was:
apache2: Syntax error on line 140 of /etc/apache2/apache2.conf: Syntax error on line 1 of /etc/apache2/mods-enabled/php5.load: Cannot load   /usr/lib/apache2/modules/libphp5.so into server: /usr/lib/apache2/modules/libphp5.so: undefined symbol: unixd_config
Action 'configtest' failed.
The Apache error log may have more information.

root@localhost:/# ls -l /etc/apache2/mods-enabled/php5.load
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root 27 Nov 17 10:31 /etc/apache2/mods-enabled/php5.load -> ../mods-available/php5.load

root@localhost:~# apache2ctl -M
php5_module (shared) --MISSNG

root@localhost:/# apache2 -v
Server version: Apache/2.4.10 
Server built:   Sep 15 2016 20:44:43
root@localhost:/# php5 -v
PHP 5.6.29-1~dotdeb+7.1 (cli) (built: Dec  9 2016 16:30:46)
Copyright (c) 1997-2016 The PHP Group
Zend Engine v2.6.0, Copyright (c) 1998-2016 Zend Technologies
with Zend OPcache v7.0.6-dev, Copyright (c) 1999-2016, by Zend Technologies
```

Following action taken:

```
root@localhost:/# apt-get install libapache2-mod-php5
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree
Reading state information... Done
libapache2-mod-php5 is already the newest version.
0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 290 not upgraded.
```

I've followed [Apache2 start error when using php5 module ( Ubuntu Server)](https://askubuntu.com/questions/536128/apache2-start-error-when-using-php5-module-ubuntu-server) link but not work my case.

Any one know that, How can troubleshoot and resolve this error?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Apache2 start error when using php5 module ( Ubuntu Server)](http://askubuntu.com/questions/536128/apache2-start-error-when-using-php5-module-ubuntu-server)

Comment: @Parto i've tried this link but not work for me !

Comment: Which command did you try and what response did you get? Kindly edit your question and include this information.

Comment: @Parto Pls check edited question

Comment: Try using `sudo apt install libapache2-mod-php` instead

Comment: @Parto `Package libapache2-mod-php is not available, but is referred to by another package` unable to install

Comment: @Parto: Read the error message! "libphp5.so: undefined symbol: unixd_config" obviously means that libphp5.so exists, else it couldn't have a dependency on that symbol. Your possible "duplicate" explicitly states that libphp5.so is missing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

libapache2-mod-php is most certainly available [here](http://packages.ubuntu.com/search?keywords=libapache2-mod-php&searchon=names&suite=all&section=all) for all currently supported Ubuntu versions. There could be [an issue with your network connection](https://www.google.com/search?client=ubuntu&channel=fs&q=askubuntu+network+troubleshoot&ie=utf-8&oe=utf-8) or [the mirror you are using to install packages](https://askubuntu.com/questions/39922/how-do-you-select-the-fastest-mirror-from-the-command-line) from or perhaps you need to [upgrade](https://askubuntu.com/questions/91815/how-to-install-software-or-upgrade-from-an-old-unsupported-release) to a supported version.